# "this" keyword in typescript decorator class is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, this, decorator

i defined a decorator class for node.js api controllers. Its functionality is working except "this". I defined a function :

```
@controller("/api/v1/blogs")
class BlogController {
  async _saveBlog(blog: BlogDoc): Promise<BlogDoc> {
    try {
      const createdBlog = await blog.save();
      return createdBlog;
    } catch (e) {
      // e.code===11000 comes from slug

      if (e.code === 11000 && e.keyPattern && e.keyPattern.slug) {
        blog.slug += `-${uniqueSlug()}`;
        // recursion. if there is error, i create a new slug and call it again
        return this._saveBlog(blog);
      }
      console.log("e in save blog", e);

      throw e;
    }
  }
 ..... //all other route handlers defined and working with no issue


  @patch("/:id")
  @use(checkRole("admin"))
  @use(checkJwt)
  async updateBlog(req: Request, res: Response) {
    const {
      body,
      params: { id },
    } = req;
    let blog: BlogDoc;
    try {
      blog = (await Blog.findById(id)) as BlogDoc;
    } catch (err) {
      return res.status(422).send(err.message);
    }

    if (body.status && body.status === "published" && !blog.slug) {
      blog.slug = slugify(blog.title, {
        replacement: "-",
        lower: true,
      });
    }
    //this not updating  or making a req to db. it just updating the values.
    blog.set(body);
    blog.updatedAt = new Date();
    console.log("_this ", this._saveBlog);

    try {
      const updatedBlog = await this._saveBlog(blog);
      return res.json(updatedBlog);
    } catch (err) {
      console.log("err in server updating", err.message);

      return res.status(422).send(err.message);
    }
  }
```

when i type `this.`, vscode shows me the options and `_saveBlod` is shown as method. But when I called it it says "this._saveBlog" is not a function. so I `console.lof(this._saveBlog)` and it returns `udnefined`. this is what is logged by `console.log(this)`

```
this in patch <ref *1> Object [global] {
  global: [Circular *1],
  clearInterval: [Function: clearInterval],
  clearTimeout: [Function: clearTimeout],
  setInterval: [Function: setInterval],
  setTimeout: [Function: setTimeout] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  queueMicrotask: [Function: queueMicrotask],
  clearImmediate: [Function: clearImmediate],
  setImmediate: [Function: setImmediate] {
    [Symbol(nodejs.util.promisify.custom)]: [Function (anonymous)]
  },
  regeneratorRuntime: {
    wrap: [Function: wrap],
    isGeneratorFunction: [Function (anonymous)],
    mark: [Function (anonymous)],
    awrap: [Function (anonymous)],
    AsyncIterator: [Function: AsyncIterator],
    async: [Function (anonymous)],
    keys: [Function (anonymous)],
    values: [Function: values]
  }
}
```

since i called `this._saveBlog` inside the patch, `this` is referring to the patch method. If i tried to call `_saveBlog` instead of `this._saveBlog`, vscode gives me this error:

```
"Cannot find name '_saveBlog'. Did you mean the instance member 'this._saveBlog'?"
```

so I feel like i m getting closer to answer thanks to comments, so the real question now how can access `_saveBlog` class method inside the patch method

Comment: How do you call `updateBlog`?

Comment: Don't use fat arrow functions if you expect `this` to work like in a regular `function`. Replace `async (err: Error, blog: BlogDoc) =>` with `async function (err: Error, blog: BlogDoc)`

Comment: Also, for the sake of consistency, try to avoid mixing code based on node-style callbacks and code based on promises. `Blog.findById()` should return a promise, and should be used as `const blogDoc = await Blog.findById(id)`. This way you could remove the `if (err)` section entirely, and you would have avoided the arrow function to begin with.

Comment: @DoronBrikman updateBlog is getting called autmatically when request hits that route

Comment: @Tomalak I corrected the code, It was a stupid mistake but i still get this._saveBlog is not function error but `this` is defined

Comment: which library do you use for `controller`, `patch` decorators?

Comment: @DoronBrikman I dont use any library. I wrote from scratch

Comment: Ok, so as you can see the `this` object is pointing to the `patch` caller object. Can you show the patch implementation?

Comment: @DoronBrikman I updated the question. you mean implementation of decorator source code?

Comment: yes, to see how do you call the wrapped function